# Show custom titles on 2 <tr> in loop

Tags: php, html-table

I have displaying 10 results from database in table on the page. Last 2 results eg. 9th and 10th rows are with custom titles on the table. The code for showing them

```
if($result_rates->num_rows>0){
    $counter = 1;
    foreach ($result_rates as $r){
         if($counter <9 )
         {    
             echo '<tr>
                      <td id="people-'.$r['number_of_people'].'">'.$r['number_of_people'].'</td>                           
                      <td>                      
                      <td>
                         <button id="'.$r['rate_id'].'" onclick="edit_row('.$r['rate_id'].')" class="btn btn-primary edit_button">Edit</button>
                      </td>
                   </tr>';
          }
          else {
        
              echo '<tr>
                      <td id="people-'.$r['number_of_people'].'">Number '.$counter.'</td>                          
                      <td>
                        <button id="'.$r['rate_id'].'" onclick="edit_row('.$r['rate_id'].')" class="btn btn-primary edit_button">Edit</button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>';                                                     
                }
                $counter++;
    }    
}
```

The result which is displayed on page is this

[image]

Is it possible to put on last two rows `Number 9` and `Number 10` different titles? The goal is both last rows be with custom 's

I've tried to add 2 `<tr>`'s in the else block but they've got doubled.

Comment: what expected outcome you want?Show us

Comment: There is second column on the right. I've deleted it for the question for simplicity. What I want is to manually add on last two rows instead of `Number 9/10` to write `Day 1/2`. In database values of this two rows are `9` and `10` if matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($result_rates->num_rows>0){
$counter = 1;
foreach ($result_rates as $r){
     if($counter <9 )
     {    
         echo '<tr>
                  <td id="people-'.$r['number_of_people'].'">'.$r['number_of_people'].'</td>                           
                  <td>                      
                  <td>
                     <button id="'.$r['rate_id'].'" onclick="edit_row('.$r['rate_id'].')" class="btn btn-primary edit_button">Edit</button>
                  </td>
               </tr>';
      }
      elseif($counter == 9){

          echo '<tr>
                  <td id="people-'.$r['number_of_people'].'">Number 9 '.$counter.'</td>                          
                  <td>
                    <button id="'.$r['rate_id'].'" onclick="edit_row('.$r['rate_id'].')" class="btn btn-primary edit_button">Edit</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>';                                                     
            }
        elseif($counter == 10){

          echo '<tr>
                  <td id="people-'.$r['number_of_people'].'">Number 10  '.$counter.'</td>                          
                  <td>
                    <button id="'.$r['rate_id'].'" onclick="edit_row('.$r['rate_id'].')" class="btn btn-primary edit_button">Edit</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>';                                                     
            }
            $counter++;
     }    
   }
```

You can also try this if you want to minimise the code:

```
if($result_rates->num_rows>0){
$counter = 1;
foreach ($result_rates as $r){
     if($counter <9 )
     {    
         echo '<tr>
                  <td id="people-'.$r['number_of_people'].'">'.$r['number_of_people'].'</td>                           
                  <td>                      
                  <td>
                     <button id="'.$r['rate_id'].'" onclick="edit_row('.$r['rate_id'].')" class="btn btn-primary edit_button">Edit</button>
                  </td>
               </tr>';
      }
      else{
          if($counter == 9){
             $custom_title= "number 9";
          }elseif($counter == 10){
             $custom_title= "number 10";
          }
          echo '<tr>
                  <td id="people-'.$r['number_of_people'].'">'.$custom_title.' '.$counter.'</td>                          
                  <td>
                    <button id="'.$r['rate_id'].'" onclick="edit_row('.$r['rate_id'].')" class="btn btn-primary edit_button">Edit</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>';                                                     
            }

            $counter++;
     }    
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write like this sort way so you don't need to write same code again.

```
if ($result_rates->num_rows > 0) {
    $counter = 1;
    foreach ($result_rates as $r) {
        if ($counter < 9) {
            $custom_titles = $r['number_of_people'];
        } else {
            $custom_titles = "Number " . $counter;
        }
        echo '<tr>
                      <td id="people-' . $r['number_of_people'] . '">' . $custom_titles . '</td>                           
                      <td>                      
                      <td>
                         <button id="' . $r['rate_id'] . '" onclick="edit_row(' . $r['rate_id'] . ')" class="btn btn-primary edit_button">Edit</button>
                      </td>
                   </tr>';
        $counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question and your comment I think you want to get last two rows dynamically(not fix 9 & 10)

```
$total_records = $result_rates->num_rows; //count number of rows
if($result_rates->num_rows>0){
    $counter = 1;
    foreach ($result_rates as $r){
         if($counter <($total_records-2) ) //(rows - 2) i.e. before last two rows
         {    
             echo '<tr>
                      <td id="people-'.$r['number_of_people'].'">'.$r['number_of_people'].'</td>                           
                      <td>                      
                      <td>
                         <button id="'.$r['rate_id'].'" onclick="edit_row('.$r['rate_id'].')" class="btn btn-primary edit_button">Edit</button>
                      </td>
                   </tr>';
          }
          else {

              echo '<tr>
                      <td id="people-'.$r['number_of_people'].'">Number '.$counter.'</td>                          
                      <td>
                        <button id="'.$r['rate_id'].'" onclick="edit_row('.$r['rate_id'].')" class="btn btn-primary edit_button">Edit</button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>';                                                     
                }
                $counter++;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, but I've tried like this and in else block I need to show two rows with different titles like in @Pritamkumar solution.